# Changing Background color after a particular date in calendar

Tags: jquery, css, date, calendar

I have a event calendar.I want to change the background color of all column after a particular date [SOC DATE] to green and  after the date red. My calendar is as follows.

```
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-19">
<td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-20">
<td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2014-02-21">
<td class="fc-day fc-sat fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2014-02-22">
<td class="fc-day fc-sun fc-widget-content fc-future fc-last" data-date="2014-02-23">
```

I managed to change the background color of that date[SOC DATE] using the following jquery.

```
$("[data-date=2014-02-22]").css("background-color","#ff9bd7");
```

But I cannot change the color of previous and past dateS.
I tried
 `$("[data-date>2014-02-22]").css("background-color","red");`
but not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
$("[data-date=2014-02-22]").prevAll().css("background-color","red");
```

---

Try this:

```
$("[data-date=2014-02-22]").closest('tr').prevAll('tr').find('td').css("background-color","red");
```

---

Try this:

```
var index = $("[data-date=2014-02-22]").index('td.fc-day');

$('td.fc-day:lt(' + index + ')').css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Only that week is colored as red. I want all the previous dates.

Comment: This is my calendar http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/247ny-aides-inc/php/php-calendar/index.php?searchid=80

Comment: I tried your code and the previous dates background colors changed. But it is no working for previous months.

Comment: Your code is changing all my td color. Please check the above link.Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: You can change `td` to `td.fc-day`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48015/discussion-between-arvei-infotech-and-felix)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('[class*="fc"]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('date') > "2014-02-22";
}).css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: Your code is working.But when i click prev or next button the background color resets to old one.  Im adding my calendar link for reference. http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/247ny-aides-inc/php/php-calendar/index.php?searchid=80

Comment: Great. But when i click on Prevoius/Next Button in calendar the function not working.I callen the function on bodyonload.Is this the problem.