# Custom background color for calendar td

Tags: jquery, html, css, calendar

I have an event calendar.I want to change the background color of `td` I refer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925372/changing-background-color-after-a-particular-date-in-calendar)** question and found out the solutions.But it didnt solve my full problem.When i use the the following `jquery`

```
$('[class*="fc"]').filter(function() {
  return $(this).data('date') > "2014-02-22";
}).css("background-color","white");
```

It changes the `background-color` and the `td` is changed as follows.

```
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-19" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

When i click the **Prev,Next,Today** buttons to navigate on the calendar, the `td` resets as follows.

```
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-19">
```

Appreciate your valuable time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you want to calculate with dates you need to use the javascript date object, here a url: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: maybe http://www.w3fools.com ?

Comment: What are `Prev,Next,Today` buttons, What do they do? I don't see them in your code. This problem can not be reproduced.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami Please Refer  the link http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/247ny-aides-inc/php/php-calendar/index.php?searchid=80

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var index = $("[data-date=2014-02-22]").index('td.fc-day');
$('td.fc-day:lt(' + index + ')').css("background-color","red");
```

and try edit in the calendar js file.